# Elastic search snap shot and backup of data of particular time interval

Tags: elasticsearch

I have elastic search index where in i will get the data continuously from some tools. i want  to take a snapshot of the data which is older than a month and delete that from the index , so that i can have less data in the index. 
Please guide me how to take the snapshot of data of a particular time interval.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how to take snapshot for particular time interval.
But To take a snapshot use the following.

```
PUT /_snapshot/my_backup
{
"type": "fs",
"settings": {
   "location": "my_backup_location"
 }
}
```

And please do refer to the link [elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/modules-snapshots.html)

Answer (score 0):

As of today elasticsearch don't allow taking snapshot for particular time interval. It only allow to take snapshot upto index level.

To achieve your end goal :

> to take a snapshot of the data which is older than a month and delete
> that from the cluster , so that i can have less data in the cluster

I will suggest to create a new index (with date appended in name) on daily basis for new data ingestion. Take daily snapshot of index which is older than 30 days and delete the index from cluster.
This will help you to save disk space in cluster as well allow you to have persistent data in your repository.

To take snapshot at index level , you can refer to doc : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshots-take-snapshot.html